# Generating report with URL generates report with no data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm generating reports via URL and one of the reports always generates report with no data. I double-checked the name of the parameter and it is correct. The report generates properly inside SSRS project with same parameter value. The parameter has no default values and is not nullable. All other reports generate properly.

If I manually open the report on report server and input a parameter value, it generates the report properly, with all data.

What else could cause this behaviour?

Comment: Hi we would need to see the actual expression to advise. Also try putting you expression into on to the screen so you can read it back. Pay attention to the placement of speech marks etc

Comment: have you checked the generated URL? Have you copied it into the browser to check what it returns and checked the URL looks as expected. If the URL is being generated from database values, I would suspect something like a special character is embedded in one of the values being passed to the report but that's just a guess.